# Create multiple records from single records from dataframe using Spark /Scala?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to create multiple records from single records to multiple records using spark and scala.

Ex :
**Name | Id | Month**
Mark | 01 | 2020-01-02
Aana | 12 | 2020-01-02

Expected Output :(adding 3 months from the Month column in original dataset)
**Name |   Id | Month**
Mark  | 01 | 2020-01-02
Mark  | 01 | 2020-02-02
Mark  | 01 | 2020-03-02
Aana  | 12 | 2020-01-02
Aana  | 12 | 2020-02-02
Aana  | 12 | 2020-03-02

Appreciate your help in this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From **`Spark-2.4`** use `sequence` in built function.

**Example**:

**`In Scala:`**

```
df.show()
//+----+---+----------+
//|Name| Id|     Month|
//+----+---+----------+
//|Mark| 01|2020-01-02|
//|Aana| 12|2020-01-02|
//+----+---+----------+

val df1=sql("SELECT explode(sequence(to_date('2018-01-02'), to_date('2018-03-02'), interval 1 month)) as Month")

df.select("Name","Id").crossJoin(df1).show()
//+----+---+----------+
//|Name| Id|     Month|
//+----+---+----------+
//|Mark| 01|2018-01-02|
//|Mark| 01|2018-02-02|
//|Mark| 01|2018-03-02|
//|Aana| 12|2018-01-02|
//|Aana| 12|2018-02-02|
//|Aana| 12|2018-03-02|
//+----+---+----------+
```

**`In Pyspark:`**

```
df.show()
#+----+---+----------+
#|Name| Id|     Month|
#+----+---+----------+
#|Mark| 01|2020-01-02|
#|Aana| 12|2020-01-02|
#+----+---+----------+

df1= sql("SELECT explode(sequence(to_date('2018-01-02'), to_date('2018-03-02'), interval 1 month)) as Month")

df.select("Name","Id").crossJoin(df1).show()
#+----+---+----------+
#|Name| Id|     Month|
#+----+---+----------+
#|Mark| 01|2018-01-02|
#|Mark| 01|2018-02-02|
#|Mark| 01|2018-03-02|
#|Aana| 12|2018-01-02|
#|Aana| 12|2018-02-02|
#|Aana| 12|2018-03-02|
#+----+---+----------+
```

Comment: @KSK,  If the answer helped you to resolve issue.. Could you **`upvote and accept`** the answer to close this thread! :-) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Check below code.

```
df.show(false)
+----+---+----------+
|Name|Id |Month     |
+----+---+----------+
|Mark|01 |2020-01-02|
|Aana|12 |2020-01-02|
+----+---+----------+
```

```
df
.withColumn("Month",expr("explode(sequence(to_date('2020-01-02'),to_date('2020-03-02'),interval 1 month))"))
.show(false)

+----+---+----------+
|Name|Id |Month     |
+----+---+----------+
|Mark|01 |2020-01-02|
|Mark|01 |2020-02-02|
|Mark|01 |2020-03-02|
|Aana|12 |2020-01-02|
|Aana|12 |2020-02-02|
|Aana|12 |2020-03-02|
+----+---+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, the simplest way is to generate months to be added and then add months as below-

```scala
 df2.show(false)
    df2.printSchema()

    /**
      * +----+---+-------------------+
      * |Name|Id |Month              |
      * +----+---+-------------------+
      * |Mark|1  |2020-01-02 00:00:00|
      * |Aana|12 |2020-01-02 00:00:00|
      * +----+---+-------------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- Id: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- Month: timestamp (nullable = true)
      */

    df2.withColumn("months_to_add", explode(sequence(lit(0), lit(2))))
      .withColumn("Month", expr("add_months(Month, months_to_add)"))
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +----+---+----------+-------------+
      * |Name|Id |Month     |months_to_add|
      * +----+---+----------+-------------+
      * |Mark|1  |2020-01-02|0            |
      * |Mark|1  |2020-02-02|1            |
      * |Mark|1  |2020-03-02|2            |
      * |Aana|12 |2020-01-02|0            |
      * |Aana|12 |2020-02-02|1            |
      * |Aana|12 |2020-03-02|2            |
      * +----+---+----------+-------------+
      */
```